# KeyError while parsing data from .xml file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, attributes, keyerror

I am a beginner and trying to parse some data from .xml files which has a structure as below.

```
<parking id="pucpr">
  <space id="1" occupied="0">
    <rotatedRect>
      <center x="300" y="207" />
      <size w="55" h="32" />
      <angle d="-74" />
    </rotatedRect>
    <contour>
      <point x="278" y="230" />
      <point x="290" y="186" />
      <point x="324" y="185" />
      <point x="308" y="230" />
    </contour>
  </space>
  <space id="2" occupied="0">
    <rotatedRect>
      <center x="332" y="209" />
      <size w="56" h="33" />
      <angle d="-77" />
    </rotatedRect>
    <contour>
      <point x="325" y="185" />
      <point x="355" y="185" />
      <point x="344" y="233" />
      <point x="310" y="233" />
    </contour>
  </space>
.
.
.
</parking>
```

There are hundreds of such files in different folders. I wrote the code below to parse data from all of those .xml files.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
import xlsxwriter

data_path = '/Users/jaehyunlee/Desktop/for_test'

# Read full directory and file name in the folder
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(data_path):
    for file in files:
        if os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() == '.xml': # filtering only for .xml files
            full_path = os.path.join(path, file)

            # Parsing data from .xml file
            tree = ET.parse(full_path)
            root = tree.getroot()

            for space in root.iter('space'):
                car = space.attrib["occupied"]
                car_int = int(car)
```

The problem occurs when I try to parse the value of attribute 'occupied'. When I run the code, it returns KeyError: 'occupied'.
For other attributes, such as 'x', 'y', 'w', 'h', it works perfectly fine.
Could someone help?

p.s. When I convert one .xml file individually, this error does not occur. But it happens when I try to iterate for all files in the folder.

Comment: Maybe first check `print(space)` and `print(space.attrib)`

Comment: did you check data in file ? Maybe there is `<space>` without `occupied`. Maybe you should check `if "occupied" in space.attrib:` or use `space.attrib.get("occupied", default_value)` to get default value if there is no `"occupied"`

Comment: you should print file name to see in which file is problem.

Comment: @furas Thank you. I checked the files and found that some of them have no attribute 'occupied' :)

Answer (score 1):

I found that this KeyError is occurred because some of the files do not contain attribute 'occupied'. To avoid this problem and continue to iterate I included 'if' under 'for'.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
import xlsxwriter

data_path = '/Users/jaehyunlee/Desktop/for_test'

# Read full directory and file name in the folder
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(data_path):
    for file in files:
        if os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() == '.xml': # filtering only for .xml files
            full_path = os.path.join(path, file)

            # Parsing data from .xml file
            tree = ET.parse(full_path)
            root = tree.getroot()

            for space in root:
                if 'occupied' in space.attrib:
                    car = space.attrib['occupied'] 
                    car_int = int(car)
```